# Deleting files after being zipped in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I wrote a small script where I can go through files that end with a specific extension and zip them into a folder. For each iteration I delete these files because I do not want them to stay there. When I do the os.remove() it will send them to the Trash.

For curiosity, is there a way I can just move the files into the zip instead of creating a copy? This will eliminate the need of deleting the files.

```
import os
import time
from zipfile import *

def main():
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    unixTime = str(timestamp)

    file_name = "a_" + unixtime + ".zip"
    zip_archive = ZipFile(file_name, "w", ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for file in os.listdir(/mypath):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            zip_archive.write(file)
            os.remove(file)

    zip_archive.close()
```

@Munchhausen
The files are generated by an .exe (written in C++) that I am calling through a subprocess.check_output method in python.

@handle
I did see that and will implement the change to eliminate close(). I could delete the temp folder as well. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Not really, no. If you want to avoid deleting files, maybe you can avoid writing them in the first place. How did these files get there? Do you have control over writing these files in the first place? The zipfile module allows to zip bytes from memory into a zipfile, circumventing the need for files on disk.

Comment: [ZipFile.open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) is a context manager and can be used with `with` (eliminating `close()`)

Comment: The title does not really reflect your question, btw.

Comment: You could also delete a [temporary directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) after picking your files from it.